# Як перекласти з російської заклик «Дерзай!» (у сенсі «Вперед, роби!»)?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як перекласти з російської заклик "Дерзай!" (у сенсі "Вперед, роби!")? Дякую.

Ось мої спроби знайти відповідь: [на r2u.org](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) та [на lingvo.ua](http://www.lingvo.ua/ru/Translate/ru-uk/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Найближче: "Сміливіше!", "Завзятіше!", "Заповзятіше!"; але може є краще?

Comment: [«Дерзай» у рос.-укр. корпусі](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?text=lexgramm&mode=para&mycorp=%28lang:ukr+|+lang_trans:ukr%29&lex1=дерзать).

Comment: [«Дерзати» у СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21683&page=738).

Comment: Гайда! Нумо! Обидва слова можна вжити у значені (вперед, роби!)

Comment: Добра відповідь, piznajko. Але "Гайда!" ніби більше заклик до спільної роботи?..

Comment: Василь Барвінок у [коментарі на фейсбуці](https://www.facebook.com/ukrse/posts/1569052649887442?comment_id=1569075379885169) пропонує просто «вперед».

Answer (score 7):

Дивно, що ви шукали в словниках слово «дерзкий», воно хоча й однокорінне з «дерзай!», та все ж воно прикметник і досить далеке по значенню від дієслова «дерзать», саме від нього утворено наказовий спосіб 2-ї ос. одн. «дерзай!». Пошукаємо це дієслово:

• [r2u.org](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on): *важитися, наважуватися, зважуватися, відважуватися, наважитися, поважитися, зважитися, відважитися, завзятися, насмілюватися, насмілитися, осмілюватися, осмілятися, осмілитися, зосмілитися, мати відвагу*. та навіть переклад саме вашого гасла: *дерзай (дерзайте)! – відважуйся (відважуйтесь)!, насмілюйся (насмілюйтесь)!*

• [lingvo.ua](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on): *дерзати, дерзнути; (осмеливаться) наважуватися, наважитися, зважуватися, зважитися, відважуватися, відважитися, насмілюватися, насмілитися, осмілюватися и осмілятися, осмілитися* – тут вони твердять, що «дерзати» є й в українській мові, та хоч це слово праслов’янського походження та його похідні є в багатьох сучасних слов’янських мовах, я сумніваюся, що воно питомо українське, [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/derzaty) цитує «Радянську Україну» 1957 року…

Особисто мені найбільше подобається «*відважуйся!*», воно й значення передає й звучить гарно, от наприклад «*наважся!*» чи «*осмілься!*» мають такі збіги приголосних, які для гасла не зовсім годяться.

Answer (score 5):

Хоч воно не часто вживане, але в українській мові є слово «дерзай(те)»:

- > *— Ото-то-то! А так, наголо — сірка! Смикнув за хвіст — та й все! Дерзай, чадо! — гукнув він, перекидаючи чарку в рот, і мерщій напрямився за батюшкою, котрий уже стояв на рундуці, дожидався.* //Панас Мирний «Повія» (частина друга, 1883–1884).
- Інші приклади можна знайти в [корпусі MOVA.info](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx).

Comment: Якщо шукати лексему "дерзати" можна знайти і Старицького, і Гончара.

Comment: @Artemix, я її й шукав. Але приклади наводив лише з «дерзай(те)» і лише зі старої класики (є ще приклад в Квітки-Основ'яненка, але там стиль самої репліки специфічний, тому не став її наводити).

Comment: Цікаво що Фасмер для рос. "дерзать" дає споріднене укр. ["дерзатися"](http://enc-dic.com/fasmer/Derzat-3770.html) ("зібратися із силами, підбадьоритися"), але я не знайшов цього слова в українських словниках.

Answer (score 1):

Почнемо з Російсько-українського словника на [Словопедії](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53396/128161.html):

> важитися, наважитися, поважитися, завзятися, насмілюватися,
>   насмілитися, (з)осмілитися.

Приклад:

> І не важся йти туди!

Дивимося [синоніми](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) до слова "[дерзати](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)":

> Недок.: нава́жуватися, зва́жуватися, ріша́тися, перемага́тися,
>   ва́житися, відва́жуватися, насмі́люватися, смі́ти, осмі́люватися,
>   ризикува́ти, дерза́ти, обісмі́люватися